# Fixing a direct rename instead of svn rename

Tags: svn

I wanted to rename a file called `test.py` to `main.py`. `test.py` is under subversion version control.  I renamed the file directly,  but realized later that I should have used `svn rename` instead.
Now `svn status` shows the following:

```
? main.py
! test.py
```

Any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rename it back, then use `svn rename`?

Comment: This is correct approach. There's no need to revert anything here.

Answer (score 2):

If you just renamed it but don't change it use: `svn revert` and then `svn rename`. In other case do `svn delete main.py` and `svn add test.py`

P.S. The advantage of the `svn rename` is that file history will be saved. When you do `delete` and the `add` the file history will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Backup the modifications made in main.py, revert test.py, delete main.py (you have a backup), svn rename test.py into main.py, copy/paste the code from your backup to main.py, and commit.

Answer (score 0):

`svn revert test.py` should solve your problem.